# JQuery complex Drag n Drop - how to add similar captioned column values in different tables

Tags: jquery, jquery-droppable

I have a requirement where I have to drop one row from a table to another table's row. During the drop some of the source columns should get added in the target. 
Example:

Source table has a `column Id`, `Number of Bundles`, `Number of tags` and `Target has Id`, `Number of Bundles`, `Number of tags`

In the above example when dropping the source row on target row, how can I add `Number of Bundles` column values and `Number of Tags` column values separately?

I have reached up to dragging and dropping and adding up the values if there are only one column in a row. Appreciate any help. I'm very new to JQuery.

script code below (I don't know how to add the html code here):

```
source.draggable({
    revert: true,
    opacity: .75,
    containment: '.container',
    cursor: 'move',
        cursorAt: { top: 35, left: 45 },
    helper: function(event) {
        return $('<div class="drag-row"><table></table></div>')
            .find('table').append($(event.target).closest('tr').clone()).end();
    },
    appendTo: 'body'
});

target.droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var classid = ui.helper.find('tr').attr('Number of Bundles');
        var name = ui.helper.find('.name').html();
        $(this).addClass('drophighlight')
                                .find('td')
                    .html(($(this).find('td').text()*1) + (ui.draggable.children("td").text() *1));


        //$(this).addClass('drophighlight')
                    //          .find('td')
                    //.html(ui.draggable.children("td").text()*1);
        //alert('row dropped ' + ui.draggable.children("td").text());
    },
    accept: source.selector
});

<div class="tcontainer">
      <table width="90%" border="1" id="t1">
        <caption>
          Source
        </caption>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Team</th>  
          <th scope="col">Number of Bundles</th>
          <th scope="col">Number of Orders</th>
          <th scope="col">Number of Shipping Tags</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="team">1</td>  
          <td class="bundle">100</td>
          <td class="name">9</td>
          <td class="name">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="team">2</td>  
          <td class="bundle">800</td>
          <td class="name">15</td>
          <td class="name">30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="team">3</td>  
          <td class="bundle">550</td>
          <td class="name">11</td>
          <td class="name">26</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tcontainer">
      <table width="90%" border="1" id="t2">
        <caption>Target</caption>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Team</th>  
          <th scope="col">Number of Bundles</th>
          <th scope="col">Number of Orders</th>
          <th scope="col">Number of Shipping Tags</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="team">1</td>  
          <td class="bundle">500</td>
          <td class="name">29</td>
          <td class="name">53</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can add the html the same way you add other code.  Paste it into the box, highlight it and hit the "code sample" button.

Comment: I added the html also. someone please look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it myself, forgot to update this. I used JQuery UI draggable & droppable along with AJAX. In the UI a div container for image, #imgHolder and in the droppable script function all business rules (calculations) AJAX is done and also a chart refresh. Please let me know if you need more info on this.

pseudo code:

```
target.droppable({
    drop : function(event, ui) {
//place your business rules (AJAX)
refreshImage();
},
    accept : source.selector        
});

function refreshImage() {
d = new Date();
var url = "/scar-inception/piechart/drawPie"+d.getTime();
//set the DIV to the img tag 
$('#imgHolder').html('<img src="'+url+'" />');
```

}